# How can I convert the special character \u0097 into NsString?

Tags: iphone

How can I convert the special character `\u0097` into NsString?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
const unichar cStringArray[] = { 0x0097, 0};
NSString* tmp = [NSString stringWithCharacters:cStringArray length:sizeof cStringArray / sizeof *cStringArray];
```

I tried the above code and bound the resulting string to a NSTextField.
The textfield did not display any character.
What glyph are you expecting?
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0097/index.htm shows a hyphen.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Some text-"]
```

where the '-' is your character entered with the Special Characters Panel ⌥⌘T